# Сохранение select при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица с селектами. Нужно, чтобы при обновлении страницы выбор селекта сохранялся. Помогите пожалуйста с решением

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button>сохранить</button>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7xLjarvz/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=localstorage

Comment: Используйте localStorage или sessionStorage, в зависимости от вашей задачи. Почитать про отличия можно например тут: https://itchief.ru/javascript/localstorage-and-sessionstorage

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f1xjvz82/